# Python multiprocessing, can't pickle thread.lock (pymongo)

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I have a class with the following method:

```
def get_add_new_links(self, max_num_links):
    self.get_links_m2(max_num_links)
    processes = mp.cpu_count()
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=processes)
    func = partial(worker, self)
    with open(os.path.join(self.report_path, "links.txt"), "r") as f:
        reports = pool.map(func, f.readlines())
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

where `get_links_m2` is another method that creates the file "links.txt". The worker is:

```
def worker(obje, link):
    doc, rep = obje.get_info_m2(link)
    obje.add_new_active(doc, sure_not_exists=True)
    return rep
```

The method `get_info_m2` visits the link and extracts some information. The method `add_new_active` adds the information to a MongoDB.

What could be wrong with my code? when I run it I get this error (and traceback):

> File "controller.py", line 234, in get_add_new_links
>
> ```
> reports = pool.map(func, f.readlines())   File "/home/vladimir/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line
> ```
>
> 260, in map
>
> ```
> return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()   File "/home/vladimir/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py",
> ```
>
> line 608, in get
>
> ```
> raise self._value   File "/home/vladimir/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line
> ```
>
> 385, in _handle_tasks
>
> ```
> put(task)   File "/home/vladimir/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/connection.py",
> ```
>
> line 206, in send
>
> ```
> self._send_bytes(ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))   File "/home/vladimir/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/reduction.py",
> ```
>
> line 50, in dumps
>
> ```
> cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj) TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [the docs](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#using-pymongo-with-multiprocessing):

Never do this:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient()

# Each child process attempts to copy a global MongoClient
# created in the parent process. Never do this.
def func():
  db = client.mydb
  # Do something with db.

proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=func)
proc.start()
```

Instead, inside the worker function a client must be initialized.

Comment: It is not true for multithreading, which works ok:
`with ThreadPool(64) as pool:
    collection = pymongo.MogoClient()["db"]["coll"]
    r = pool.map(do_something, collection)
            pool.join()`